# Is there a bash or shell script I could make to kill all ads in an application?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a bash/shell script I could make to kill all ads in a application, e.g. Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari does not have an API that you can access with bash or sh, so not directly.

Assuming that UNIX tools are acceptable you could (in theory) [write a server using bash and nc](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/09/06/web-server-on-bash-in-one-line/).

This server could act as a proxy server and filter out adverts on the way through.

You can then configure mobile safari to use it.

This would, of course, require that the proxy be exposed on whatever network you were using mobile safari on.

Comment: @D3ATH — It is. You have a language where you have to do most things from scratch, and you have a complicated problem.

Comment: Wow idk if I could do that I'm not that smart

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. A bash/sh script can't tell the difference between an embedded ad, normal content, and other embedded content because that's not what it's for (specifically, it's not made to specifically deal with HTML output). What you want is an adblocker.

Comment: You could write a bash/sh script specifically to deal with HTML output. It wouldn't be my first choice of language, but it isn't impossible.

Comment: You could, but we ARE talking about writing a bash/sh script from scratch to do so, and this would include making a blacklist from scratch. It's a retardedly difficult task, and certainly not worth the trouble. The OP would be much better off just searching for an adblocker.

Comment: Well if you look at it this way most ads are from adchoice(google adsense)

Comment: @Palladium apple don't allow adblockers on their mobile devices it ain't that easy for mobile I'd rather do a blacklist then search for a adblocker